# Why does control flow analysis fail when using generics in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic type that allows for either of the properties in an object to be `undefined`, but never both:

```
type RequireOne<T> =
  | {
      a: NonNullable<T>
      b: NonNullable<T>
    }
  | {
      a: NonNullable<T>
      b: undefined
    }
  | {
      a: undefined
      b: NonNullable<T>
    }
```

Now, if I use this type when declaring functions, it works beautifully with concrete types:

```
const test1 = ({ a, b }: RequireOne<string>): string => a ?? b
```

But it fails if I try to make the same function generic as well:

```
const test2 = <T>({ a, b }: RequireOne<T>): T => a ?? b 
// ERROR: Type 'NonNullable<T> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Is this expected behavior from TypeScript, and if so, why?

Comment: Looks like you've run into [ms/TS#50652](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50652); your specific version works because `RequireOne<string>` is essentially a discriminated union (checking `a` for nullishness eliminates union members), but TS is unable to see `RequireOne<T>` as a discriminated union because the discriminant involves a type parameter.  I'm not sure if it's "expected" or not, but that's what seems to be going on.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I think that issue is related to my question. Thanks for drawing it to my attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) don't play nicely together.  In this particular case it looks like you've run into the issue reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#50652](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50652) in which a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) is not seen as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) when the intended discriminant property is generic.

Here you are trying to discriminate `RequireOne<T>` by checking the `a` property for [nullishness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish), but the type checker doesn't do it.

Since there's an issue about it then the behavior is at least *known*, but that doesn't *necessarily* mean it's "expected" given that the issue is on the [Backlog](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/milestone/29) and marked as "Needs Investigation" (as of today, 2023/08/04).  So it might not get resolved for a while, if ever.

But again, in general, TypeScript really can't perform arbitrary higher order analysis on generic types.  [`NonNullable<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) is [as of TypeScript 4.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing) equivalent to the [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `T & {}`.  For any *specific* type `T`, the compiler will understand that `T & {}` is distinguishable from `undefined`.  But it can't abstract such things to the general statement "for all types `T`, `T & {}` is distinguishable from `undefined`".  Until and unless that is hardcoded into the compiler by someone, you'll have this problem.